# rewrite in seo friendly way complex url in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi I'm developing a website and all .php files are located in the main folder on the server (where .htaccess is).
So index.php and productDetail.php are in the same folder.
I want to redirect a url like this :

**http://www.mywebsite/productDetail/PRODUCTNAME**

to

**http://www.mywebsite/productDetail.php?product=PRODUCTNAME**

so that I can link the first link version instead of the second.

I also need to redirect a more complicated version, like:

**http://www.mywebsite/PRODUCTCATEGORY/PRODUCTSUBCATEGORY/productDetail/PRODUCTNAME**

to

**http://www.mywebsite/productDetail.php?product=PRODUCTNAME&category=PRODUCTCATEGORY&subcategory=PRODUCTSUBCATEGORY**

My .htaccess currently uses the following rules that I think are making really difficult this operation because I've been working on it a lot of time :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Comment: there is only one main folder. i.e.  MAIN with index.php and productDetail.php files in it. The /it or /en are just ways to change URL for different browser languages

Comment: ok in that case won't `http://www.mywebsite/productDetail/PRODUCTNAME` be actually `http://www.mywebsite/en/productDetail/PRODUCTNAME` ?

Comment: @anubhava Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @anubhava Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. At this point I got it work with an URL http://www.mywebsite/en/productDetail?product=PRODUCTNAME , by the way the productDetail.php file is in the same folder of the index.php file and there are no folders "en" or "it". I need now to make the working URL above look like http://www.mywebsite/en/productDetail/PRODUCTNAME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /it%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/(it|en)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(en)/(productDetail)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&product=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(it)/(dettagliProdotto)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&product=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(en)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(productDetail)/([\w-]+)/?$ $4.php?lang=$1&product=$5&category=$2&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(it)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(dettagliProdotto)/([\w-]+)/?$ $4.php?lang=$1&product=$5&category=$2&subcategory=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks anubhava, you gave me a great tip! now it work, i mean that i'm able to read the variable product in the code and the url doesn't change, but it's like every link or external ref in the code now use as base_url =mywebsite.com/en/productDetail/ , so,for example, all the includes and links are not working anymore. do you have any idea on how to fix it from the htaccess or I need to find a solution in the html /php code?thanks

Comment: That is due to your use of relative paths. You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: i got another small question, I don't know if you can help me about it. what if I would like to change "productDetail" in RewriteRule ^(en|it)/(productDetail)/([\w-]+)/?$ $2.php?lang=$1&product=$3 [L,QSA,NC] according to language? I mean in italian productDetail is "dettagliProdotto"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Rule of the following form :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^productdetail/productname/?$ /productdetail.php?productname [NC,L]
```

The Rule with Regex patterns :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /productdetail.php?productname [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect /productDetail/foo to /productDetail.php?product?foo.

Comment: unfortunately is not doing the trick, looks like it's ignored :(

Comment: @pipizanzibar could you be more spacific about the issue you are having?

Comment: it's like everything in the code tries to look for resources in the folder /productdetail/beach, so every relative url is starting from this one: mystic.com/productdetail/beach , but as i wrote, i got every file in the same folder. Both index.php and productdetail.php